# Prevent Windows 10 from automatically re-ordering taskbar hover previews in a group?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

**Scenario:** I open 3 Visual studio 2015 instances in particular order so that when switching between them via task bar hover preview I know exactly which project is at first position and so on. I can simply move my mouse on the grouped Visual studio icon in taskbar and without paying attention click on one of the 3 hover previews of the instance I want to open.

**Problem:** But, due to some unknown reasons Window 10 sometimes reorders these previews (inside the group) and I often click on the wrong VS instance expecting it to be another. 
Furthermore, I cannot drag-drop within hover previews to re-order them and the only way to reset the order is to close all instances and open them again one-by-one in the order I want.

What is causing this behavior? How can I at least re-order these hover previews without closing and re-opening all VS2015 instances?

[image: Image of Windows 10 taskbar hover preview of 3 Visual studio instances]

Answer (score 1):

You can re-order the previews with the [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) with drag-and-drop within a group of instances.

[Screenshot 7+TaskbarTweaker with highlighted option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d60DV.png)

Comment: You mean drag-and-drop within single group of previews right?

Comment: Yes, within the groups, you can reorder the hover-preview-instances by drag-and-drop.